# No Scaling/Fixed Output Resolution support?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm writing a Win32 C++ program to change screen resolution and scaling mode of various machines. I'm running Windows 7 but targetting Windows XP. The program works on my Windows 7 laptop, in terms of enumerating compatible display modes:

```
if (listModes)
{
    DEVMODE dmPossibleMode = { 0 };
    ZeroMemory(&dmPossibleMode, sizeof(dmPossibleMode));
    dmPossibleMode.dmSize = sizeof(dmPossibleMode);

    cout << "Key: BD = Bit density/Bits per pixel, SM = Scale mode" << endl;
    cout << "+-----+-----------+-------+----+----+" << endl;
    cout << "|  ID |   Dims    | Freq. | BD | SM |" << endl;
    cout << "+-----+-----------+-------+----+----+" << endl;
    for(int iModeNum = 0; EnumDisplaySettings(dd.DeviceName, iModeNum, &dmPossibleMode) != 0; iModeNum++)
    {
        ostringstream resString; resString << dmPossibleMode.dmPelsWidth << "x" << dmPossibleMode.dmPelsHeight;
        ostringstream freqString; freqString << dmPossibleMode.dmDisplayFrequency << "Hz";
        ostringstream bbpString; bbpString << dmPossibleMode.dmBitsPerPel;
        ostringstream scaleString; scaleString << dmPossibleMode.dmDisplayFixedOutput;
        cout << "|" << setw(4) << iModeNum << " ";
        cout << "|" << setw(10) << resString.str() << " ";
        cout << "|" << setw(6) << freqString.str() << " ";
        cout << "|" << setw(3) << bbpString.str() << " ";
        cout << "|" << setw(3) << scaleString.str() << " |" << endl;
    }
    cout << "+-----+-----------+-------+----+----+" << endl;
}
```

### Gives me:

```
+-----+-----------+-------+----+----+
|  ID |   Dims    | Freq. | BD | SM |
+-----+-----------+-------+----+----+
|   0 |   640x480 |  59Hz |  8 |  0 |
|   1 |   640x480 |  60Hz |  8 |  0 |
|   2 |   640x480 |  60Hz |  8 |  2 |
|   3 |   640x480 |  60Hz |  8 |  1 |
|   4 |   640x480 |  73Hz |  8 |  0 |
|   5 |   640x480 |  75Hz |  8 |  0 |
|   6 |   640x480 |  75Hz |  8 |  2 |
|   7 |   640x480 |  75Hz |  8 |  1 |
|   8 |   640x480 |  59Hz | 16 |  0 |
|   9 |   640x480 |  60Hz | 16 |  0 |
|  10 |   640x480 |  60Hz | 16 |  2 |
[ etc.                              ]
```

But over on the Windows XP desktops, the output is like:

```
+-----+-----------+-------+----+----+
|  ID |   Dims    | Freq. | BD | SM |
+-----+-----------+-------+----+----+
|   0 |   640x480 |  59Hz |  8 |  0 |
|   1 |   640x480 |  60Hz |  8 |  0 |
|   2 |   640x480 |  60Hz |  8 |  0 |
|   3 |   640x480 |  60Hz |  8 |  0 |
|   4 |   640x480 |  73Hz |  8 |  0 |
|   5 |   640x480 |  75Hz |  8 |  0 |
|   6 |   640x480 |  75Hz |  8 |  0 |
|   7 |   640x480 |  75Hz |  8 |  0 |
|   8 |   640x480 |  59Hz | 16 |  0 |
|   9 |   640x480 |  60Hz | 16 |  0 |
|  10 |   640x480 |  60Hz | 16 |  0 |
[ etc.                              ]
```

I.e. scaling mode all says '0'. Can anyone offer some insight as to why this might be? Much appreciated!

Comment: The MSDN Library article for EnumDisplaySettings() does *not* promise that the field will have a value, you must check dmFields.  The video device driver spec was significantly revised at Vista with a new driver model called WDDM.  That probably has something to do with it.

Comment: Indeed, so is it likely it's impossible to determine supported scaling modes from Windows APIs?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to check the `dmPossibleMode.dmFields` against `DM_DISPLAYFIXEDOUTPUT`. If that bit is not set, the value you use at `dmPossibleMode.dmDisplayFixedOutput` has not been initialized, so it is worthless checking it.

> If DM_DISPLAYFIXEDOUTPUT is not set, this member must be zero.

from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183565%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

If I remember correctly however these "stretching" values have meaning only on laptop screens, but this might be wrong, don't base on it.

Comment: That only needs to be set when you pass a DEVMODE struct to *apply* settings. I am using `EnumDisplaySettings` in a loop to retrieve all supported mode properties. I do note that it says it only populates `dmBitsPerPel`, `dmPelsWidth`, `dmPelsHeight`, `dmDisplayFlags` and `dmDisplayFrequency` - in which case, my question now becomes to how do I enumerate supported scale modes..? I've now asked this elsewhere.